# Object doesn't support property or method 'item' IE 9

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to find all buttonitems.  In chrome and modern browsers this works fine but in ie9 I am having the error above.  I can't change the HTML on the page only the javascript on the page.  In chrome I can use document.getElementsByClassName() but in ie 9 I can't even though I should be able to probably because the website has to run in comparability with Quirks.  I have tried rewriting the code to work without this and believe I have got the elements with the code

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1){
    if (document.all) {
        var allElements = document.all;
    } else {
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    }

    // Empty placeholder to put in the found elements with the class name
    var oldHrefs = [];

    for (var i = 0, ii = allElements.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].className == 'ButtonItem') {
            oldHrefs[oldHrefs.length] = allElements[i];
        }
    }   
}
else
{
    var oldHrefs = document.getElementsByClassName('ButtonItem');
}
```

But I then need to loop through the code and remove the href and add an onclick which is when I revive my next error.  Object doesn't support property or method 'item'.  Any ideas what I can do to correct the code below?

```
for (var i = 0; i < oldHrefs.length; i++) {
    var thisHref = oldHrefs.item(i).getAttribute('href');
    if (thisHref != null) {
        if (thisHref.includes('Act=1468')) {
            oldHrefs.item(i).removeAttribute("href");
            oldHrefs.item(i).setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="' + thisHref + '";this.removeAttribute("onclick");');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `[]` instead of `item` like `oldHrefs[i].getAttribute('href')`

Comment: And `.indexOf('Act=1468') > -1` instead of `.includes('Act=1468')`

Comment: Added the above comment and deleted the answer. As you say, when appear to be in comp.mode./quirks mode, to many _normal_ things won't work, so the above suggestion should hopefully do it.